# Adding new row to Gridview explanation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have the following code in c#,

```
GridView grdViewOrders = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "Customer Name : " + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CustomerName").ToString();
            cell.ColumnSpan = 6;
            cell.CssClass = "GroupHeaderStyle";
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            grdViewOrders.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + intSubTotalIndex, row);
            intSubTotalIndex++;
```

And I need some explanation regarding this line

```
GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
```

what is the first second and forth parameters are about in the constructor of GridViewRow

Thanks

Comment: See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.gridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the link - [GridViewRow Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.gridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx)

1. rowIndex :The index of the GridViewRow object in the Rows collection of a GridView control.
2. dataItemIndex :The index of the DataItem in the underlying DataSet.
3. rowType : One of the DataControlRowType enumeration values.
4. rowState : A bitwise combination of the DataControlRowState enumeration values.

Was this what you needed?